# Am I able to use foundation without knowing much about Magento? Website is currently running magento version2.0

Tags: magento, zurb-foundation

I have a programming background Microsoft. I have been asked to take over the website at work (multi million dollar business using Magento2 Enterprise). I know php and JavaScript and I am familiar with JQuery and various plug-ins. However I know nothing about Magneto. Am I able to edit the visual layout of the website (that is currently using foundation framework) without knowing much about Magneto? OR do I need to learn to use/program Magneto before I can edit the visual look of our webs-site?

Comment: Magento can seem to be complicated at first but once you get to grips with it's concepts and architecture, it becomes second nature. My advice is to start by reading this guide relating to themes and designs. It will introduce to Magento's block concepts, layout definitions and templates. The one thing I say to any novice Magento developer working for me is to remember that every template file has an associated block file where the template logic is handled. Templating is a good place to start. https://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/designers_guide_to_magento.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can change colours and various CSS styles without knowing much about Magento, but if you want to start changing the templates (HTML) or the way the framework functions, you'll need to learn.

Comment: Thanks Robbie. Straightforward answer. Also thanks to Ash for the link it was very helpful.